# How I can break the JavaScript infinite loop through Chrome Debug Protocol programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am using [Chrome Debug Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) in Node.js, and the program accepts user's input 
as code and run it in Chrome through Chrome Debug Protocol, just like the snippet below:

```
const Chrome = require('chrome-remote-interface')

Chrome(async (client) => {
  const {
    Page,
    Runtime
  } = client
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      Page.enable(),
      Runtime.enable()
    ])
    Runtime.evaluate({ expression: `while (1) {}` })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

But if the code has infinite loop like `while (1) {}`, the Chrome's tab will stay still forever. Is there any way to exit the infinite loop (or just simply stop the running JavaScript) programmatically instead of killing the process?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, JavaScript is a single threaded runtime. Only one piece of code can be executed at a time.

Long answer: Yes, if you write a **non-blocking** looping mechanism that releases control to the event loop. If the execution stack never has a chance to clear (e.g. while(true) {}), then control is never released to the event loop and additional code cannot be run. This prevention of additional code exection is referred to as **blocking**.

Using your very basic example it would be possible to interrupt the process if the loop was written as such:

```js
(function loop() {
  // code here...
  setTimeout(loop); // release execution to the event loop...
})();
```

Comment: I cannot control the code that runs because it's from user's input. So It may contain infinite loop like `while (true) { ... }`.

Comment: In that case the code must be instrumented, there is no way that I know of, to block the execution of a call stack.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to change the source code of Chromium, and I am trying to clone the repo, god blesses me.

Comment: In my opinion that's probably too low level, you might want to look into parsing the AST and generating a different JavaScript file that allows you to interrupt blocking loops, modules like **istanbul** already do this type of JavaScript instrumentation to monitor runtime code coverage.